# Polygon overlay in leaflet map

Tags: python, leaflet, polygon

I am creating an interactive map using `ipyleaflet` using the following code:

```
from ipyleaflet import Map, Polygon


polygon = Polygon(
    locations=[[(38.844185,-4.804621),(39.241299,-1.899833),(40.74308,-2.205491),(40.34742,-5.17429),(38.844185,-4.804621)],[(39.365192,-1.941078),(40.867912,-1.567062),(41.276688,-4.670904),(39.775406,-4.976737),(39.365192,-1.941078)],[(39.706161,-1.849863),(41.207623,-1.465817),(41.617561,-4.594476),(40.117233,-4.908839),(39.706161,-1.849863)],[(39.702591,-5.033657),(40.101254,-2.077048),(41.602196,-2.389729),(41.204681,-5.413605),(39.702591,-5.033657)]],
    color="green",
    fill_opacity= 0.5,
    fill_color="green"
)

m = Map(center=(38.5531, -4.6914), zoom=6)
m.add_layer(polygon);

m
```

The ouptut looks like this: 
[image]

I am wondering how can I make the intersection of the polygons not be fully transparent. Looking at the attributes https://ipyleaflet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference/polygon.html in the documentation, I don't see any option?

An example of the desired output can be seen in the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got bad results because ipyleaflet subtracts ovellaped polygons (you can see it in second example in the documentation link you posted, "Polygon with hole")

You need to add each polygon separately, I changed your code a bit, now it creates and applies polygons in loop:

```
from ipyleaflet import Map, Polygon

poligons = [[(38.844185,-4.804621),(39.241299,-1.899833),(40.74308,-2.205491),(40.34742,-5.17429),(38.844185,-4.804621)],
            [(39.365192,-1.941078),(40.867912,-1.567062),(41.276688,-4.670904),(39.775406,-4.976737),(39.365192,-1.941078)],
            [(39.706161,-1.849863),(41.207623,-1.465817),(41.617561,-4.594476),(40.117233,-4.908839),(39.706161,-1.849863)],
            [(39.702591,-5.033657),(40.101254,-2.077048),(41.602196,-2.389729),(41.204681,-5.413605),(39.702591,-5.033657)]]

m = Map(center=(38.5531, -4.6914), zoom=6)

for poly in poligons:
    polygon = Polygon(
        locations= poly,
        color="green",
        fill_opacity= 0.5,
        fill_color="green"
    )
    m.add_layer(polygon);

m
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: good to know, I did not find any reference in the documentation to this behaviour when using a list of polygons instead of adding them one by one with a for loop.  Would be great if they add it. Thanks for the answer!! I'll award the bounty as soon as it allows it! Well deserved